# Symfony clear cache component after deploy

Tags: caching, deployment, components, symfony

Hi is there way to clear ALL cached data from symfony cache component?

Here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html on bottom is: (i need console command)

```
$cacheIsEmpty = $cache->clear();
```

and command:

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

keeps this cache untouched

I am lookig for console command witch i can call in *.sh script every deploy.

EDIT (example):

Default input options:

```
 $cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
 $defaultInputOptions = $cache->getItem('mainFilter.defaultInputOptions');

 if (!$defaultInputOptions->isHit()) {
      // collect data, format etc.
      $expiration = new \DateInterval('P1D');
      $defaultInputOptions->expiresAfter($expiration);
      $cache->save($defaultInputOptions);
 } else {
      return $defaultInputOptions->get();
 }
```

But if i change something in 'collect data, format etc.' on my machine and after that make deploy (git pull, composer install, bin/console cache:clear...) then new version on server has still valid cache (1 day) and take data from it...

Comment: why ./bin/console cache:clear is not enough?

Comment: In question is update - example and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make any service you want implement the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheClearer\CacheClearerInterface` to be used by symfony **native** cache:clear

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheClearer\CacheClearerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

final class SomeCacheClearer implements CacheClearerInterface
{
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $filesystemAdapter)
    {
        $this->cache = $filesystemAdapter;
    }

    public function clear($cacheDir)
    {
        $this->cache->clear();
    }
}
```

Config is done by the tag **kernel.cache_clearer**

```
cache_provider.clearer:
    class: AppBundle\Path\SomeCacheClearer
    arguments:
        - 'my_app_cache'
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.cache_clearer }
```

EDIT: precision about cache as a service:

Your cache service could be defined like that

```
my_app_cache:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter
```

Or if you want to specify a namespace and ttl

```
my_app_cache:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter
    arguments:
        - 'my_cache_namespace'
        - 30 #cache ttl  (in seconds)
```

So you should **not** use

```
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
```

But with service injection

```
$cache = $this->get('my_app_cache');
```

Comment: Hi THX for answer. I must add `use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AdapterInterface;` and in arguments give `@cache.app`. But it don't work - no error and after `bin/console cache:clear` still data loads from valid cache

Comment: If you put a breakpoint or a `var_dump("called");exit;` in method clear(), is it called?

Comment: in console i see 'called' so yes

Comment: Yep thank you. It works without any arguments in service.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

At the end - suffices edit only `services.yml` and add:

```
appbundle.cachecomponent.clearall:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.cache_clearer }
```

I am new in symfony so i hope that is right solution.